# jquery pass a data-attribute to a callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I have the following function   where obj is a table row

```
calculate: function(obj) {     
  var sum = 0;   
  $('option:selected', obj).attr('value', function(i,v){
    sum += Number(v);
  });
  $('td:last', obj).text(sum);
  HoursSum.table.trigger('sumChanged', sum);
}
```

At this point it is correctly retrieving the value attribute. My question is:
How can I access a `data` attribute of the same selected option? I have tried:

```
 ('option:selected', obj).data('duration', ....
.data('data-duration')
.attr('duration')
```

However none of them seem to work. The jQuery documentation says that `data()` should do the trick but in this case for some reason it doesn't. Any ideas?

Example HTML

```html
<td class='col-sm-1' style='background-color:pink'>
  <select id='22505.30' class='form-control-sm' style='font-size: 11px;' name='shifts' onchange="submitEntry(this.value,this.id, 22505, '30.06.2018')">
    <option value='0'>Select</option>
    <option data-duration='10.60' data-shiftstart='21:00' data-shiftend='06:00' value='120'>test</option>
    <option data-duration='1.00' data-shiftstart='12:00' data-shiftend='13:00' value='118'>test1</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Use `$('option:selected', obj).data('duration')`. You need to remove the `data-` prefix when using `data()` and add it when using `attr()`; your logic there is backwards. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: Deja vu... please share your HTML. Are you populating your options via AJAX by any chance?

Comment: Don't you mean `calculate: function(obj) {     
  var sum = 0;   
  $('option:selected', obj).each(function() {
    sum += Number(this.value);
  });
  $('td:last', obj).text(sum);
  HoursSum.table.trigger('sumChanged', sum);
}`

Comment: The options are loaded via php at page load from a database. 
HTML:
    <td class='col-sm-1' style='background-color:pink'>
<select  id='22505.30' class='form-control-sm' style='font-size: 11px;' name='shifts'  onchange="submitEntry(this.value,this.id, 22505, '30.06.2018')">
<option value='0'>Select</option>
<option data-duration='10.60' data-shiftstart='21:00' data-shiftend='06:00' value='120' >test</option>
 
<option data-duration='1.00' data-shiftstart='12:00' data-shiftend='13:00' value='118' >test1</option>
</select>
</td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code. but we need to see your HTML to help you with better code.

```
calculate: function(obj) {     
  var sum = 0;   
  $('option:selected', obj).each(function(){
    var data = $(this).data();
    sum += data.duration;
  });
  $('td:last', obj).text(sum);
  HoursSum.table.trigger('sumChanged', sum);
}
```

Comment: This returns undefined for data.duration

Comment: Nevermind - error was on my side. This works. It correctly gets the values. Thank you!